# I need to animate an elevator image in my webpage and move it to preset locations in the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright so I am making an elevator simulator. The buisness logic of everything is fine, I am using queues. The problem I am having is moving the elevator from one floor to the next in the queue. I am using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript / Jquery. So far the two approaches I have been trying is Jquery's animate method and CSS translate. I have not yet been able to find a decent answer. My most recent attempt has to do with using invisible elements in the DOM in order to have coordinates to move the elevator to. I will provide code snippets for further explanation.

[image: Current Elevator implementation]

That is a picture of the webpage, as you can see I need to be able to move the elevator to any given floor at any given time.

```js
// Called when user selects the Start button
$('#btn-start').click(function() {
  // Start the Simulation
  let destination = $('#second-floor').offset();
        $("#elevator").animate( {right: destination.left, bottom: destination.top}, 4000, "linear", function(){console.log("Elevator finished moving")} );

  //});
});
```

```css
.elevator-visual {
  width: 55%;
}

.elevator {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 10vw;
  margin-left: 6vw;
}

.floor {
  position: relative;
}

.hidden-destination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10vw;
  left: 11vw;
  background: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}

.floor-bound {
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 15vw;
}

#first-floor,
#second-floor {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.floor-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #777;
  margin-right: 6vw;
}

#floor-four-lable {
  margin-top: 15vw;
}

.btn-start{
    position: static;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 21px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #b77110;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Elevator Diagram -->
<div class="elevator-visual">
  <div class="floor">
    <div class="hidden-destination"></div>
    <p id="floor-four-lable" class="floor-title">Floor 4</p>
    <hr id="forth-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <div class="hidden-destination"></div>
    <p class="floor-title">Floor 3</p>
    <hr id="third-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <div class="hidden-destination"></div>
    <p class="floor-title">Floor 2</p>
    <hr id="second-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <img id="elevator" class="elevator" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
  <div class="floor">
    <div class="hidden-destination"></div>
    <p class="floor-title">Floor 1</p>
    <hr id="first-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <button id="btn-start" class="btn-start">Start</button>
</div>
```

As you can see in the JS, I toggle some classes when the start button is pressed, then I grab the info for the destination from the top of the queue, and right now I am stuck on animating the elevator (my most recent attempt looks dumb lol) to be able to go to any floor I want.

Here is also a link to the repository if you would like to clone and open with live-server: https://github.com/Amalazing/Elevator-Simulator

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Don't post code as pictures, please copy paste the code we need as actual text to your question.

Comment: I created a snippet from your code. Unfortunately it's not working since you didn't give us all the code. Please update accordingly so we can see what your problem is exactly.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know a good way to move the elevator up to visit each floor. I would love to change the code snippet to show the elevator moving up to the second floor but that is not the issue. Once its there I do not know how to move it to any other floor that I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using css' transition and minor javascript you can animate your object (whether it be an img or what have you, I've used text based span for my demo) to a part of your page via inline javascript calls from your button's onclick - I've written a quick and dirty demo at the bottom of this post for you.

More on css transitions: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Note: I've not included your queue list mechanism because this wasn't a part of your question... but it shouldn't be too tough to implement my example into your project - good luck.

```css
.lift {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.flrfour {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 85%;
  left: 5%;
}

.flrthree {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 5%;
}

.flrtwo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35%;
  left: 5%;
}

.flrone {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5%;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="flrfour"> floor 4 </span>

<span class="flrthree"> floor 3 </span>

<span class="flrtwo"> floor 2 </span>

<span class="flrone"> floor 1 </span>

<span id="lft" class="lift">lift</span>
<div class="buttons"><button onclick="document.getElementById('lft').style.bottom = '10%';">1</button><button onclick="document.getElementById('lft').style.bottom = '35%';">2</button><button onclick="document.getElementById('lft').style.bottom = '60%';">3</button><button
    onclick="document.getElementById('lft').style.bottom = '85%';">4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

Just animate the bottom to wherever you want it to go.

I used fixed px values for height here so that it is easier to understand what's happening (At least I hope it is easier)

I get the offset (just the top value) from the element I want to animate to. Then I set the top value of the elevator to match with the top value of the destination.

```js
// Called when user selects the Start button
$('#btn-start').click(function() {
  // Start the Simulation
  let destination = $('#second-floor').offset().top;
        $("#elevator").animate( {top: destination}, 200, "linear" );

  //});
});

$('.btn-to-floor').on('click', function() {
  let floor = $(this).data('floor');
  let floors = $('.floor').length;
  // eq(floors - floor) needed to so some magic calculations (you could also just use some hardcoded id here based on data attribute. 
  let destination = $('.floor').eq(floors - floor ).find('.floor-bound').eq(0).offset().top;
        $("#elevator").animate( {top: destination}, 200, "linear");
});
```

```css
.elevator-visual {
  width: 55%;
  position: relative;
}

.elevator {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 6vw;
  bottom: 0;
}

.floor {
  height: 180px; /* height of elevator + text + line */
}

.floor-bound {
  width: 75%;
}

.floor-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #777;
  margin-right: 6vw;
}

.btn-start{
    position: static;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 21px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #b77110;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Elevator Diagram -->
<div class="elevator-visual">
  <div class="floor">
    <p id="floor-four-lable" class="floor-title">Floor 4</p>
    <hr id="forth-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <p class="floor-title">Floor 3</p>
    <hr id="third-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <p class="floor-title">Floor 2</p>
    <hr id="second-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <p class="floor-title">Floor 1</p>
    <hr id="first-floor" class="floor-bound" />
  </div>
  <img id="elevator" class="elevator" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
</div>

<button id="btn-start" class="btn-start">Start</button>
<button class="btn-to-floor" data-floor="1">1</button>
<button class="btn-to-floor" data-floor="2">2</button>
<button class="btn-to-floor" data-floor="3">3</button>
<button class="btn-to-floor" data-floor="4">4</button>
```